# Unable to upgrade ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, updates, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

I currently have ubuntu version `"20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"` running and I want to upgrade it to `22.04`.

I have ran the following commands and it's outputs:

```
# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu focal InRelease
...                          
Hit:10 http://dell.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
# sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra node-hosted-git-info imagemagick libzmq5
  python2.7-minimal libmagickwand-6.q16-6 python2.7 python3-rsa node-tar
  imagemagick-6.q16 libopenexr24 libmysofa1 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
# sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra node-hosted-git-info imagemagick libzmq5
  python2.7-minimal libmagickwand-6.q16-6 python2.7 python3-rsa node-tar
  imagemagick-6.q16 libopenexr24 libmysofa1 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
# sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

I have tried everything possible but it's always stucked on `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`.

Am I missing something here? Also, let me know if I need to provide any more details.

Thanks.

Comment: @Bodo that package was workspacesclient and I have just upgraded it. Now, `apt update` command is clean as well.

Comment: Updated, Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem for release upgrade 22.04 → 22.10. [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462632/ubuntu-22-04-problem-with-release-upgrade-to-22-10)