# Ubuntu 22.04 problem with release upgrade to 22.10

Tags: 22.04, do-release-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 22.04. I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.10.
This is what I have done:

1. I have changed from LTS to normal in the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file.
2. Then I have run `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove` to install updates for Ubuntu 20.04.
3. Then `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 22.10.

Unfortunately, I get a prompt to install all  updates for the current release (Ubuntu 22.04) before upgrading to U22.10.  I have run 2. and 3. again, but got the same prompt.

What should I do to upgrade to U22.10? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

- Run: `sudo apt list --upgradable`
- Then upgrade manually all listed packages with `sudo apt upgrade package`
- Then `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove`
- Finally: `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade